# How do I import a mercurial patch that has a different directory structure

Tags: mercurial

I have a patch, made with `hg export 42` in another repository, that modifies the files

```
asd/fgh/foo/bar.c
asd/fgh/foo/fish.h
boo/hoo.txt
```

I need to import this patch to a repository that has the structure like:

```
src/foo/bar.c
src/foo/fish.h
boo/hoo.txt
```

Is there any command that can accomplish this - I can re-run the `hg export` on the old repo if needed, and am willing to ignore the files that have *same* path (e.g. `boo/hoo.txt`)

I thought originally that `hg import -p3 patch.diff` in `repository/src` would have done this, but apparently it still wants to create the `asd/fgh/` hierarchy in the top level (and place .rej files there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to go into the patch file and just change the names.  A few search and replaces and you're probably good to go.

The only mercurial command I know that accepts a filename translation map is the 'convert' command, so there's probably a solution to be found by running the old repo through something like `hg convert --filemap thefilemap exportingrepo newexportingrepo`, where thefilemap has in it:

```
rename asd/fgh src
```

then export it from newexportingrepo and import into the receiving repo.

Me, I'd probably hand edit the patch. :)

Answer (score 0):

you could always do it in two changes. rename the directories then apply the patch.